# How to use PhpStorm autocomplete from class inside container array

Tags: php, phpstorm

Yesterday I started using an container array which contains my classes. Now I have the Problem, that I can't use autocomplete for the Classes Functions.

Here's a small example of what my container looks like:

```php
$container[PDO::class] = function () use ($container) {
    return new PDO('mysql:host=' . $container['database_host'] . ';dbname' . $container['database_name'], $container['database_user'], $container['database_pass']);
};

$container[\Envms\FluentPDO\Query::class] = function () use ($container) {
    return new \Envms\FluentPDO\Query($container[PDO::class]());
};

$container[\Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader::class] = function () use ($container) {
    return new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader($container['template_dir']);
};

$container[\Twig\Environment::class] = function () use ($container) {
    return new \Twig\Environment(new $container[\Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader::class]());
};

return $container;
```

Is there a way to use autocomplete for the functions inside classes which are created within the `$container` array?

Comment: You may utilize PhpStorm's Advanced Metadata functionality: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html#map (when you have a container as a class: `$container->get(SOMETHIG)`) 2) When it's just an array... I do not think this will work. But will work for a class that implements `\ArrayAccess` interface: see this comment/ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-33309#focus=Comments-27-5133593.0-0

Comment: As for just an array... I may only say -- look at the PhpStorm's `ArrayShape` PHP attribute -- https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-attributes#arrayshape -- might work (have not tried it myself on array variable).

Comment: Another possible thing to look at: `ArrayShape` equivalent from PHPstan: https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types#array-shapes (PhpStorm supports PHPstan in general, it comes with corresponding plugin already bundled). NOTE: It's still PhpStorm that parses PHPstan syntax comments.

Comment: Note: all ideas proposed above have in mind that it will be used this way: `$container[SOMETHING]->`. (that array elements returns some instance). If you want to use it as `$container[SOMETHING]()` then I do not think that it would work here...